# How do I implemet release method?

Tags: ios, memory-management, release-management

Objective c has release method. I want to create my own method that duplicate objective c method. But I don't know hot to free a memory.

```
-(void) release
{
 if(retainCount == 1)
 {
  [self freeMemory];
 }
 else
 {
  retainCount --;
 }
}

-(void) freeMemory
{

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to have your release method? Every class that inherits from NSObject has (adopts) one that method.

Comment: I want to know how apple implement release method.

Comment: They call [self dealloc]. See my answer below. But you still shouldn't do it.

Comment: If your question is "what's the low-level functionality of dealloc" then it's probably just calling free() on the pointer to the NSObject (free being the opposite of the C malloc() function), but then again, who knows what other clever undocumented stuff it might be doing.

Comment: Yes, my question was about low-level functionality of dealloc.

Comment: Okay, well in that case your freeMemory method can probably just call free(self);

Comment: If this is for learning purposes, I would suggest grabbing the source to the GNUStep runtime as it contains implementations of all the standard Cocoa style retain/release/autorelease/dealloc methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that you would call [self dealloc], but you really shouldn't be doing stuff like this, *ever ever ever*. Under ARC it's not even possible to write this kind of code.

Your method exactly duplicates the functionality of the release method that your class will already have inherited from NSObject, so it's very difficult to see what the point is.

If you want to do something extra when release is called, why not just call [super release]?

Can you explain what it is you want to do at a higher level - maybe there's an alternative approach?

Answer (score 0):

In your `freeMemory` function you should release all retained class members and that's it.

Comment: No, you still need to call [self dealloc], or at least [super dealloc]. dealloc doesn't just release the class members, it also has to release the infrastructural data used by NSObject, e.g. the struct header containing the class pointer and retainCount data.

Comment: I thought he will be calling [super dealloc] in his class's dealloc function and in freeMemory he will be releasing his custom resources.

Comment: Yes, but if he overrides the release method then dealloc never gets called unless he calls it himself. dealloc is called by release.